# limit of the function of two variables ??

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Here is the function :
\begin{equation}
f(x,y)=a^2 \left(\frac{x}{a^2-3 x^2}-\frac{y}{3 y^2-a^2}\right).
\end{equation}
We know that $y\geq x \geq 0$, $~a$ is a constant and $a^2=x^2+xy+y^2$.

I want to derive the limit of the function in the case $x\rightarrow a/\sqrt{3}=r_0$ and  $y\rightarrow a/\sqrt{3}=r_0$.

One method is to take $x=r_0-\delta$ and $y=r_0+\delta$ and $a=\sqrt{3}r_0$. Then substituting them into $f(x,y)$, I can obtain 
\begin{equation}
f(r_0,\delta)=-\frac{2 r_0^3}{4 r_0^2-\delta ^2}.
\end{equation}
Thus in the limit of $\delta \rightarrow 0$, we can get the result $-r_0/2$.

The another method is to substitute $a^2=x^2+xy+y^2$ into $f(x,y)$ directly, I get 
\begin{equation}
-\frac{(x+y) \left(x^2+x y+y^2\right)}{(2 x+y) (x+2 y)},
\end{equation}
then set $x=y=r_0$. I get the limit is $-2r_0/3$.

Obviously, the two results are different. So which method is reliable?

Comment: You should re-wite the third line. You mean that $x\to a/\sqrt 3$ and $y\to a/\sqrt 3.$ Else it makes no sense. I was tempted to stop reading there,as I often do  at a point like this.

Comment: @user254665: yes, I edit my question as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Write $x:= ua$, $y:=v a$. We then have to investigate
$$\hat f(u,v)=a\left({u\over 1-3u^2}+{v\over 1-3v^2}\right)$$
under the constraint
$$u^2+uv+v^2=1\ .$$
The constraint defines an ellipse in the $(u,v)$-plane whose axes are at $45^\circ$ with respect to the coordinate axes. A parametrization of this ellipse is given by
$$u(\phi)={1\over\sqrt{3}}\cos\phi-\sin\phi,\quad v(\phi)={1\over\sqrt{3}}\cos\phi+\sin\phi\qquad(-\pi\leq\phi\leq\pi)\ .$$
The function $g(\phi):=\hat f\bigl(u(\phi),v(\phi)\bigr)$ simplifies to
$$g(\phi)=-{2a\over\sqrt{3}}\ {\cos\phi\over 1+2\cos(2\phi)}\ .$$
The point $x=y={a\over\sqrt{3}}$ in question corresponds to the point $u=v={1\over\sqrt{3}}$ on said ellipse, hence to $\phi=0$ on the parameter axis. This means that we have to compute
$$\lim_{\phi\to0} g(\phi)=-{2a\over 3\sqrt{3}}\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

The first method makes no sense: once you decide that $x=r_0-\delta$, $y=r_0+\delta$, you have
$$
x^2+xy+y^2=(r_0+\delta)^2+(r_0-\delta)(r_0+\delta)+(r_0-\delta)^2=3r_0^2+\delta^2=a^2+\delta 
$$
and your condition $x^2+xy+y^2=a^2$ is not satisfied.

In the second method you are not showing your work so I cannot comment on it, but you are getting the right result.

Comment: It seems that if there is no the condition $a^2=x^2+xy+y^2$, the first method still succeeds and the corresponding result should be OK.  Right?

Comment: It depends on what you want. Without  restriction, the limit does not exist. In your first method you are replacing your constraint by the new constraint $y+x=2r_0$, so you are calculating something else.